# I have to enter twice for code to complete

Tags: java

I am working on a Pig Game. I have two submit an answer twice for my code to work. For example. if i want to roll the dice, i have to submit r two times for it to roll. I can not find an instance where i am printing the same thing twice, and its been constantly in my code since i started working on the project. Any ideas?

The only time it does not have this issue is on the first run after a turnover.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3_Part1_Final {
    static int playerScore = 0;
    static int playerTotal = 0;
    static int dice = 0;
    static final int FINAL_SCORE = 20;
    static int playerTwoScore = 0;
    static int playerTwoTotal = 0;
    static boolean gameOver = false;
    static boolean turnOver = false;
    static char repeat;
    static String input;
    static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerOneTurn();
        PlayerTwoTurn();
        if (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
            System.out.print("Current Score: Player 1 has " + playerTotal);
            System.out.print(", Player 2 has " + playerTwoTotal);
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        }
        if (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
            System.out.print("Current Score: Player 1 has " + playerTotal);
            System.out.print(", Player 2 has " + playerTwoTotal);
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        }
    }

    public static void PlayerOneTurn() {

        //System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + playerTotal); // welcome line
        //System.out.print(". Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
        while (turnOver == false) {

            do {
                System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + playerTotal); // welcome line
                System.out.print(". Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
                input = key.next(); // input = next key entered
                repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if (repeat == 'r') // if input letter = r
                {
                    dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // set dice to number between 1-6
                    System.out.println("Player 1 rolled: " + dice); // display number, signifying the amount rolled
                    

                    if (dice == 1) // if the number rolled happens to be 1...
                    {
                        playerScore = 0; // reset score to 0
                        System.out.print("Player 1 lost their turn! ");
                        System.out.print("Player 1 total is " + playerTotal);
                        turnOver = true; // go to next player.
                        break;

                    }

                    else {
                        playerScore += dice; // add dice amount to player score
                        System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + playerScore);// print out total amount earned //
                                                                                    // after last roll
                        System.out.print(" Enter (r)oll or (s)top: "); // repeat question.
                        input = key.next();
                        repeat = input.charAt(0);
                        if (playerScore >= 20) {
                            playerTotal = playerScore;
                            gameOver = true;
                        }
                    }

                } else if (repeat == 's') // if neither option is called
                {
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect entry, please try again"); // prompt retry
                    input = key.next();
                }

            } while (turnOver == false || dice != 1);
            playerTotal += playerScore;
            playerScore = 0;
            if (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
                // System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
                gameOver = true;
                while (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE)
                    ;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PlayerTwoTurn() {

        System.out.print("Player 2 turn total is " + playerTwoTotal); // welcome line
        System.out.print(". Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
        while (turnOver == false) {
            do {
                input = key.next(); // input = next key entered
                repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if (repeat == 'r') // if input letter = r
                {
                    dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // set dice to number between 1-6
                    System.out.println("Player 2 rolled: " + dice); // display number, signifying the amount rolled

                    if (dice == 1) // if the number rolled happens to be 1...
                    {
                        playerScore = 0; // reset score to 0
                        System.out.print("Player 2 lost their turn! ");
                        System.out.println("their total is " + playerTwoTotal);
                        turnOver = true; // go to next player.
                        while (playerTwoTotal < 20)
                            ; // if the playerTotal is under 20

                    }

                    else {
                        playerTwoScore += dice; // add dice amount to player score
                        System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + playerTwoScore);// print out total amount earned //
                                                                                        // after last roll
                        System.out.print(" Enter (r)oll or (s)top: "); // repeat question.
                        input = key.next();
                        repeat = input.charAt(0);
                    }
                } else if (repeat != 's') // if neither option is called
                {
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect entry, please try again"); // prompt retry
                    input = key.next();
                }

            } while (turnOver == false || dice != 1);
            playerTwoTotal += playerTwoScore;
            System.out.println("Player 2 score is " + playerTwoTotal);
            playerTwoScore = 0;
            if (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
                // System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
                gameOver = true;
                while (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE)
                    ;

                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Current Score: Player 1 has 0, Player 1 has 0

Player 1 turn total is 0. Enter (r)oll or (s)top: r

You rolled: 4

Player 1 turn total is 4 Enter (r)oll or (s)top: r
r

You rolled: 5

Player 1 turn total is 9 Enter (r)oll or (s)top: r
r

You rolled: 1

Turn over
Current Score: Player 1 has 0, Player 2 has 0

Player 2 turn total is 0. Enter (r)oll or (s)top: r

You rolled: 1

Turn over
Current Score: Player 1 has 0, Player 1 has 0

Player 1 turn total is 0. Enter (r)oll or (s)top: r

You rolled: 3

Player 1 turn total is 3 Enter (r)oll or (s)top: r
r

You rolled: 6

Player 1 turn total is 9 Enter (r)oll or (s)top:
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the R programming language or Apache PIG. Incorrect tags have been removed.

Comment: Next: this would be a great time to fire up your debugger and try to isolate the bug and see why it is occurring.

Comment: I did in fact go into my debugger before posting this question, however i am not sure i'm using it correctly. My class never went over external debuggers, so i have just been using an online one. I know they are not great. Even then, Nothing beneficial was pointed out to me, it does not point to any reason as to why it is requiring two entries. I know i probably could figure this out with a proper debugger, but i sadly do not have one setup and the ones i tried have not helped me discover anything useful.

Comment: Look for everyplace where you accept input (i.e., key.next()).

Comment: And now im just annoyed at myself. The else statements where i added the dice number to the player score, i had an unnecessary key.next() function. None of the debuggers even hinted at that. I only had it there because i thought i had to have a key.next() right after my prompt, but since the code loops back up, it automatically does that for me. thank you!